# Java HashMap returns null value for some keys . . . sometimes

Tags: java, hashmap

I have created a hashmap the contains a string for the key and and an object as the value.  However, when I try to retrieve some of the values, I get a null result.

```
// This returns all the keys and their values.
    for (String key : DevicesUsed.devicesUsedMap.keySet()) {
        if(DevicesUsed.devicesUsedMap.containsKey(key)) {
            System.out.println(key + " exists");
            System.out.println(key + "\t" + DevicesUsed.devicesUsedMap.get(key));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Key does not exist.");
        }
    }

    // This only works for some of the keys, that worked in the above code.
    System.out.println(DevicesUsed.devicesUsedMap.get("WHITEALL"));     // Works.
    System.out.println(DevicesUsed.devicesUsedMap.get("REDCOVE"));      // Returns null.
```

[screen shot of the console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbyzB.png)

Very confused as to why some of the keys exist in one block, but not in the other.

Comment: Didn't you ask this same question yesterday or this morning?

Comment: When you run this with a debugger, what information do you gain? And have you created a test program, a [mcve] to try to isolate the error yet? If so, please post. If not, consider making.

Comment: @J-Alex The key looks like a `String`, so that shouldn't be it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your screenshot message `'WHITEALL exist'` contains one space, but `'REDCOVE  exist'` - two.

It looks like you have `'REDCOVE '` as key instead of `'REDCOVE'`.

Comment: Yup, looks like all the keys are 8-character strings, space-padded on the right.

Comment: I appears I forgot to strip off the trailing spaces when I created the keys.  They were being read from a byte array.  Now it appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

From you screenshot REDCOVE definitely has a space at the end. Try using `System.out.println(DevicesUsed.devicesUsedMap.get("REDCOVE "));`